# Deploy FastAPI microservice in Kubernetes via OpenFaaS

Tags: python, kubernetes, aws-lambda, fastapi, openfaas

I have a big application structured with **[FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/)** (with many routers), that runs in AWS Lambda. I want to migrate it to a container inside **[Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/)**. From my research, **[OpenFaaS](https://www.openfaas.com/)** is a great solution.
However I can't find documentation about how to do this.

*Does anyone has references or a better solution?*

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the python or Ruby

You can create the docker file and use it for creating the docker images and simply deploy it on Kubernetes.

```
FROM ruby:2.7-alpine3.11

WORKDIR /home/app
COPY    .   .

RUN bundle install

CMD ["ruby", "main.rb"]
```

For OpenFass they have provided good labs with documentation to create the Async function etc.

Labs : https://github.com/openfaas/workshop

If you are looking for [examples](https://github.com/openfaas/faas/tree/master/sample-functions) you can check out the official repo only : https://github.com/openfaas/faas/tree/master/sample-functions

**Extra**

There is also another good option [Knative](https://knative.dev/docs/) or [Kubeless](https://kubeless.io/)

You can find the python Kubeless example and CI/CD example : https://github.com/harsh4870/kubeless-kubernetes-ci-cd

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However the solution proposed with Dockerfile does not seem scalable to me. And from the suggested links I didn't see a relationship between OpenFaaS and FastAPI. Perhaps it is best to explore another solution.

Comment: We have FastAPI app deployed using ECS Fargate and CICD runs using AWS CodePipeline. Haven't had any issues with scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Try use a template to build an upstream FastAPI application as an OpenFAAS function. This will create a docker image you can run and deploy in your Kubernetes cluster.

You can see how to do so in the following [github repo](https://github.com/vst/openfaas-template-python-fastapi)